# Evince search shortcut

Tags: evince

Where I can request a new feature for evince?
I would appreciate that the ctrl+f shortcut could be changed to move focus to the search instead of toggle the search bar. It's annoying to change the search pattern or even to use the search twice. I also could suggest that the ESC can be used to  dismiss the search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File a bug report tagged "Wishlist" on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince), or marked "enhancement" at [GNOME Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=evince).